# Meaning of "to hold each heart the heart that shares" in a poem by Byron

Tags: phrase-meaning, poetry

[A poem by Byron](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Works_of_Lord_Byron_(ed._Coleridge,_Prothero)/Poetry/Volume_3/Hebrew_Melodies/If_that_High_World):

> If that high world, which lies beyond
>   Our own, surviving Love endears;
>   If there the cherished heart be fond,
>   The eye the same, except in tears—
>   How welcome those untrodden spheres!
>   How sweet this very hour to die!
>   To soar from earth and find all fears
>   Lost in thy light—Eternity!
>
> It must be so: 'tis not for self
>   That we so tremble on the brink;
>   And striving to o'erleap the gulf,
>   Yet cling to Being's severing link.
>   Oh! in that future let us think
>   **To hold each heart the heart that shares**,
>   With them the immortal waters drink,
>   And soul in soul grow deathless theirs!

What could be the meaning of the bolded phrase? "To hold **with** each heart the heart that shares" would make it a bit less hazy for me but still mysterious.

Comment: To **hold** can mean **to  deem or judge**.

Comment: @TRomano -- oops, I should have combed through the dictionary entry before posting! Thank you!

Comment: I'd parse it as *To hold [judge, classify] each heart **to be** the [a] heart that shares [good things with others]*. But it's Lit Crit.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's not LitCrit, that's just glossing or paraphrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To hold each heart the heart that shares

The speaker is saying

> To hold each heart

to cherish / respect / behold the "heart" (love)

> the heart that shares

meaning the love that is unselfish.

The speaker is contemplating what is after death

> which lies beyond

and possibly concluding

> With them the immortal waters drink,
>   And soul in soul grow deathless theirs!

that those that unselfishly love or that love itself can have a certain immortality.

Such is the romanticism of Lord Byron.